# laravel not sending out mail when mail implements ShouldQueue

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

I have my mailable class set up to implement the ShouldQueue interface, and also using the Queueable trait. Now, when I send the mail, it goes to the jobs table, `php artisan queue:work` runs the jobs without failure, I can see that the job has been processed, but I don't get the mail in my inbox.

However, when I remove the ShouldQueue from the implemented interfaces, the mail gets sent fine and I get the mail in my inbox.

Also, whenever I'm on local, the queued mail gets sent and I can see the mail in my inbox.
Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What is your queue driver and mail driver?

Comment: The queue driver is "database", and my mail driver is "smtp". The app is hosted on a shared hosting with cpanel, so I have the mail settings of the host set up properly

Comment: Perhaps the job is silently failing? Check your failed jobs table.

Comment: The jobs table is usually cleared out. But for testing sake, if I stop the queue worker and fire the mail event, I can see the jobs waiting to be processed in the jobs table. It gets processed successfully, as the failed_jobs table is usually empty too, and there are no entries in the log file. Another case is when I'm queuing a NOTIFICATION that gets sent to database and mail, it gets the recorded in database, but no mail received